# How to use classes from another jar file dynamically

Tags: java, jar

right now I am struggling with very specific problem. I am building modular app where most of the modules are strictly separated so there is no coupling. However some modules can use the same large parts of code so I thought of to make them as another modules and handle it via some dependency system to avoid building modules with the same parts of code.
My question is, as the modules are optional, is there a way how to build one module (jar file) dependent on another module? In other words, is it possible to build separate but coupled jar files I know they will be always together in specified file paths?

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean with "app" an adroid app or a plain java application (program)?

Comment: just pure desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

In your first JAR, at the start in main method, check if the another JAR file is exists.

If it does not exist throw an error message and don't proceed till you find the second JAR file.